# VB.net output datetime with timezone and offset

Tags: vb.net, date-formatting

I wish to construct a `DateTime` which looks like below in Visual Basics:

`Wed Aug 23 2017 10:00:00 GMT+0530`

Can anyone please suggest how to construct a `DateTime` info where timezone info could also be shown as above?

Comment: Do you want something where you can specify the time zone (the "Construct" in the title), or do you want to simply *display* the time zone with the datetime?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like below...

```
Dim dt as DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow
Dim output as String = dt.ToLocalTime().ToString("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss tt ""GMT"" zzz")
Console.WriteLine(output) 'Outputs Aug 23, 2017 11:16:29 AM GMT +01:00
```

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

A DateTime has a [Kind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921(v=vs.110).aspx) which is one of DateTimeKind.Local, DateTimeKind.Utc, or DateTimeKind.Unspecified, so although it has *some* time zone information, it is too limited to specify another offset.

A [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) can hold other offsets, so it may suit your purposes better:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim hereAndNow = DateTime.Now
        Dim utc = DateTime.UtcNow
        Dim noTzi = Date.SpecifyKind(utc, DateTimeKind.Unspecified)

        Dim inIndia As New DateTimeOffset(noTzi, TimeSpan.FromHours(5.5))

        Console.WriteLine(hereAndNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss K"))
        Console.WriteLine(utc.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss K"))
        Console.WriteLine(inIndia.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT' K"))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

> 2017-08-23 11:36:55 +01:00
>   2017-08-23 10:36:55 Z
>   2017-08-23 10:36:55 GMT +05:30

I had to set the Kind of the DateTime variable `utc` to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` to be able to use it in the DateTimeOffset constructor.

You should use the [K custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-k-custom-format-specifier) for *displaying* time zone information.