# What datetime format is this and how can I achieve this in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datetime, format

I need to make `DateTime.Now` output a value in this format:

`2021-04-01T12:34:56-06:00`

What is this format called and how do I achieve it? This part in particular confuses me: `-06:00`. What is that?

Comment: This might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835952/vb-net-output-datetime-with-timezone-and-offset

Comment: I believe that's the time zone? 06:00UTC?

Comment: Which are you using vb.net or vba?  They are different and the answer will depend on which one you are using.

Comment: Take a read of this post [ISO 8601 Datetime understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906340/iso-8601-datetime-understanding) it tries to explain just what you are asking.

Comment: Also (for VBA): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600875/how-to-get-the-current-datetime-in-utc-from-an-excel-vba-macro/23968601

Comment: It's `DateTime.Now.ToString("O")` without the milliseconds.

Comment: You want `DateTime.Now().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz")`. The value of `DateTime.Now().Kind.ToString()` is "Local", so it will figure out the zzz part for you.